# Dialyzer cannot recognize types from dependencies

Tags: elixir, dialyzer

### Background

I have an umbrella app where I use a dependecy called [ETS](https://hexdocs.pm/ets/ETS.KeyValueSet.html). This dependency has a type called [`set_options`](https://hexdocs.pm/ets/ETS.KeyValueSet.html#t:set_options/0) that I use in some of my specs.

### Problem

The code works fine, but dialyzer is complaining. Namely:

```
lib/web_interface/persistence.ex:11:20:unknown_type
Unknown type: ETS.set_options/0.
________________________________________________________________________________
lib/web_interface/persistence.ex:11:65:unknown_type
Unknown type: ETS.t/0.
```

Which then cause a ton of cascading errors.

To try and fix this, I added the following to my **root** `mix.exs` file (the one from the umbrella app, not the one from the child app):

```
  def project,
    do: [
      apps_path: "apps",
      version: "2.1.7",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps(),
      dialyzer: [
        plt_add_deps: :app_direct,
        plt_add_apps: [
          :ets
        ],
        plt_core_path: "plts",
        plt_local_path: "plts"
      ]
    ]
```

And then run:

- `mix dialyzer --plt`
- `mix dialyzer`

This did not work and the output was the same.

I then tried adding this to the `mix.exs` of the child app in question (alongside the previous changes):

```
  def application do
    [
      mod: {WebInterface.Application, []},
      extra_applications: [:logger, :ets]
    ]
  end
```

Unfortunately, nothing worked and I still get the same dialyzer errors.

### Question

How can I fix dialyzer so it recognized types from my dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an error from my side, namely I was not interpreting the documentation correctly.

The correct types are:

- `ETS.KeyValueSet.set_options()`
- `ETS.KeyValueSet.t()`
- `ETS.table_identifier()`

This was more apparent from reading the [source code](https://github.com/TheFirstAvenger/ets/blob/c1689f289bd86e2867278f92e91a93699cdfb6f4/lib/ets/key_value_set.ex#L51-L55) as posted in this thread:

- https://elixirforum.com/t/dialyzer-cannot-recognize-types-from-dependencies/61779/2?u=fl4m3ph03n1x

Answer (score 1):

`ETS` [does not define](https://github.com/TheFirstAvenger/ets/blob/master/mix.exs#L37-L41) any application and hence neither `plt_add_apps: [:ets]` nor `extra_applications: [:ets]` could have any effect.

For this particular case, one should explicitly define a path to `ETS`’ `ebin` directory as described [in the documentation](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir#paths).